# How to monitor if new document is created for specific user

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Say we have the following code in Cloud Functions Typescript code:

```
functions.firestore.document("collectionName/"+ID).onCreate(...
```

How am I supposed to pass ID to Cloud Functions code above while ID is the current user ID or username?
Currently the authentication is done in the app and user enters the app, but I am not sure how Cloud Functions on the server can know who is this user who logged in and interacts with the app?

I need to monitor "onCreate" event only for the relevant user.

Answer (score 2):

You don't "pass" anything to a Firestore onCreate trigger.  It just runs **any time** a matching document is created.  You have to specify the pattern of the documents to match.  When a matching document is created, the function runs, and you can use the provided `context` to know the ID of the document that was created.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created_2) for an example of an onCreate trigger:

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => { ... }
```

In the provided example above, the trigger matches all documents in the users collection.  The `userId` wildcard contains the ID that was matched.  You can use that to know the ID of the document that was created.  Using the [documentation for wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st#wildcards-parameters) you can get the ID from the context parameter passed to the function.

Here is the example from the documentation that uses an onWrite trigger:

```
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // If we set `/users/marie` to {name: "Marie"} then
      // context.params.userId == "marie"
      // ... and ...
      // change.after.data() == {name: "Marie"}
    });
```

Comment: Thx for clarifying @Doug, totally missed the concept of the wildcards. Yes no need to pass anything actually.